# AWS Athena does not see records generated by Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, serverless-framework, amazon-athena

I have a data pipeline where AWS API Gateway triggers lambda, which inserts events into Kinesis stream and writes them to S3 for Athena to query.

I defined my stack using "serverless framework", as below:

```
service: analytic-event-collection

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'staging'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-1'}
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  httpApi:
    cors: true
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - 'kinesis:PutRecord'
          Resource:
            - '*'

custom:
  kinesisSteamName: 'event-collection-stream-${self:provider.stage}'
  s3AnalyticsStore: 'page-view-store-${self:provider.stage}'
  s3AthenaStore: 's3-analytic-data-${self:provider.stage}'
  glueName: 'analytics-store-${self:provider.stage}'

functions:
  collect:
    handler: handler.collect
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /collect
          method: post
    environment:
      KINESIS_STREAM_NAME: ${self:custom.kinesisSteamName}

resources:
  Resources:
    S3AnalyticsStore:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName:  ${self:custom.s3AnalyticsStore}

    KinesisStreamData:
      Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
      Properties:
        Name: ${self:custom.kinesisSteamName}
        RetentionPeriodHours: 24
        StreamModeDetails:
          StreamMode: ON_DEMAND

    FirehoseDeliveryIAMPolicy:
      Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
      Properties:
        PolicyName: "EventCollectionPolicy"
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 's3:AbortMultipartUpload'
                - 's3:GetBucketLocation'
                - 's3:GetObject'
                - 's3:ListBucket'
                - 's3:ListBucketMultipartUploads'
                - 's3:PutObject'
              Resource: 
                - !Join 
                  - ''
                  - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                    - !Ref S3AnalyticsStore
                - !Join 
                  - ''
                  - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                    - !Ref S3AnalyticsStore
                    - '/*'
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'kinesis:DescribeStream'
                - 'kinesis:GetShardIterator'
                - 'kinesis:GetRecords'
              Resource: !GetAtt 
                - KinesisStreamData
                - Arn
        Roles:
          - !Ref FirehoseDeliveryIAMRole
      DependsOn:
        - KinesisStreamData
        - S3AnalyticsStore

    FirehoseDeliveryIAMRole:
      Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Sid: ''
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: firehose.amazonaws.com
              Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  'sts:ExternalId': !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'

    KinesisFirehoseDeliveryStream:
      Type: 'AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream'
      Properties:
        DeliveryStreamName: !Join 
          - ''
          - - '${self:custom.kinesisSteamName}-'
            - 'deliver'
        DeliveryStreamType: KinesisStreamAsSource
        KinesisStreamSourceConfiguration:
          KinesisStreamARN: !GetAtt 
            - KinesisStreamData
            - Arn
          RoleARN: !GetAtt 
            - FirehoseDeliveryIAMRole
            - Arn
        S3DestinationConfiguration:
          BucketARN: !GetAtt 
            - S3AnalyticsStore
            - Arn
          BufferingHints:
            IntervalInSeconds: 300
            SizeInMBs: 5
          CloudWatchLoggingOptions:
            Enabled: 'false'
          CompressionFormat: GZIP
          EncryptionConfiguration:
            NoEncryptionConfig: NoEncryption
          RoleARN: !GetAtt 
            - FirehoseDeliveryIAMRole
            - Arn
      DependsOn:
        - FirehoseDeliveryIAMPolicy
        - FirehoseDeliveryIAMRole

    S3AthenaStore:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName:  ${self:custom.s3AthenaStore}

    AnalysisGlueDatabase:
      Type: AWS::Glue::Database
      Properties:
        CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
        DatabaseInput:
          Name:  !Join 
            - ''
            - - '${self:custom.glueName}-'
              - 'db'
          Description: "Analysis aws Glue database"
      DependsOn:
        - S3AthenaStore

    AnalyticsGlueRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      DependsOn:
        - S3AnalyticsStore
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            -
              Effect: "Allow"
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - "glue.amazonaws.com"
              Action:
                - "sts:AssumeRole"
        Path: "/"
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          ['arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole']
        Policies:
          -
            PolicyName: "S3BucketAccessPolicy"
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                -
                  Effect: "Allow"
                  Action: 
                    - "s3:GetObject"
                    - "s3:PutObject"
                  Resource: 
                    !Join
                      - ''
                      - - !GetAtt S3AnalyticsStore.Arn
                        - "*"
  
    AnalyticsGlueCrawler:
      Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
      Properties:
        Name: "AnalysisCrawler"
        Role: !GetAtt AnalyticsGlueRole.Arn
        DatabaseName: !Ref AnalysisGlueDatabase
        Targets:
          S3Targets:
            - Path: !Ref S3AnalyticsStore
        SchemaChangePolicy:
          UpdateBehavior: "LOG"
          DeleteBehavior: "LOG"
        Schedule:
          ScheduleExpression: "cron(00 0/1 * * ? *)"
        RecrawlPolicy: 
          RecrawlBehavior: CRAWL_NEW_FOLDERS_ONLY
      DependsOn:
        - AnalyticsGlueRole
        - AnalysisGlueDatabase

    AnalyticsAthenaWorkGroup:
      Type: AWS::Athena::WorkGroup
      Properties: 
        Name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-wg
        WorkGroupConfiguration: 
          ResultConfiguration:
            OutputLocation: 
              !Join
                - ''
                - - 's3://'
                  - !Ref S3AthenaStore
      DependsOn:
        - S3AthenaStore
     
  Outputs:
    AthenaDataStore:
      Description: "Athena Data Store"
      Value: !Ref S3AthenaStore
      Export:
        Name:
          Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-athena"
      
    AthenaDataStorePath:
      Description: "Athena Data store path"
      Value: !Join
        - ''
        - - 's3://'
          - !Ref S3AthenaStore

    AnalyticData:
      Description: "event data"
      Value: !Ref S3AnalyticsStore
      Export:
        Name:
          Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-data"

    AnalyticDataDB:
      Description: "Glue Database"
      Value: !Ref AnalysisGlueDatabase
      Export:
        Name:
          Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-db"

    AthenaWorkGroup: 
      Description: "Athena work group"
      Value: !Ref AnalyticsAthenaWorkGroup
      Export:
        Name:
          Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-athena-workgroup"
```

The pipeline works up to a point. I have a bucket named `page-view-store-staging` with records for emitted events.

However, Athena does see not any records or I am querying for data incorrectly. When I open the Athena console, it sees my database: `analytics-store-staging-db` and a single table - `page_view_store_staging`.

My S3 bucket has records. They are in the form of
bucket/year/month etc so the path is: `page-view-store-staging/2022/07/11/20/` and inside a gzipped text file with JSON, for example:

```
{"anonymous_id":"123","url":"-","event_type":"pageView","timestamp":"2022-07-11T20:59:51.144Z","source_ip":"69.113.177.222","user_agent":"curl/7.54.0"}
```

When I try to execute a query, the response is:

```
SELECT * not allowed from relation that has no columns
This query ran against the "analytics-store-staging-db" database, unless qualified by the query.
```

I looked at glue console and it sees the database and the table, and the table has `objectCount: 0 UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER`. I also tried invoking the crawler manually. It starts and runs. Yet, there are no errors and no records.

What am I doing wrong? How do I check whether `glue` is working and/or debug it?

Comment: You have to provide more info. What are the records? Json? Did you actual open files generated by firehose? Can you confirm they are ok?

Comment: Yes, files are there. Will add the details to the question above.

Comment: Are the records in different lines? Athena will not read json files, if the records are not separated by a new line.

Comment: Yes, each record is on its' own line, like:
```{"anonymous_id":"123","url":"-","event_type":"pageView","timestamp":"2022-07-12T03:29:47.186Z","source_ip":"69.113.177.222","user_agent":"curl/7.54.0"}
{"anonymous_id":"123","url":"-","event_type":"pageView","timestamp":"2022-07-12T03:29:50.726Z","source_ip":"69.113.177.222","user_agent":"curl/7.54.0"}
{"anonymous_id":"123","url":"-","event_type":"pageView","timestamp":"2022-07-12T03:29:53.628Z","source_ip":"69.113.177.222","user_agent":"curl/7.54.0"}
```

Comment: If you go a step back, can you make it work using AWS console? It is just to see if the problem is with your template or its a general issue and nothing works.

Comment: I tried playing with `glue` crawler's config. Nothing has changed - crawlers do not populate Athena tables.

Comment: Then go one more step back. Create manually a text file in some dummy bucket with few of your records, and try to see if you can make it work using console.

Comment: I went to `Glue` again. Using the console created another database, and manually created a new crawler with the exact same settings using my existing bucket with events, except for the IAM role which, IAM created for me during the steps. After triggering a crawl, that database is populated with my events, and Athena queries are working. Is there a problem with my role definition?

Comment: The policy that Glue wizard made has:
```       "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::page-view-store-staging*"
            ]
  ``` while mine has ```
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::page-view-store-staging*",
``` - `[...]` around `Resource` ARN for AWS and none for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my bucket access policy had incorrect syntax. The correct one is:

```
    Policies:
      -
        PolicyName: "S3BucketAccessPolicy"
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            -
              Effect: "Allow"
              Action: 
                - "s3:GetObject"
                - "s3:PutObject"
              Resource: 
                - !Join
                  - ''
                  - - !GetAtt S3AnalyticsStore.Arn
                    - "*"
```